# Dynamically add mixin to a class depends on attribute value in python

Tags: python, inheritance, mixins

I want to dynamically add a mixin class in an object without effecting any other objects of that class. I have an external service that determine which mixin should be used for a particular object.

I am currently using a metaclass to dynamically add a base class to an object. But the issue is, if I change base class of any object, it effects all other objects as well. Here is a simplified sample code snippet:

```
class M(type):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = type.__call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        if hasattr(obj, "mixin"):
            obj.__class__.__bases__ = (obj.mixin,) + obj.__class__.__bases__
        return obj


class MixinA:
    name = "A"
    attr1 = 100


class MixinB:
    name = "B"
    attr2 = 200


class A(metaclass=M):
    pass


class B(A):
    def __init__(self, some_value):
        self.mixin = external_function(some_value)


b1 = B('X')  # Let's say it should use MixinA
print(b1.name, b1.__class__.__base__)

b2 = B('Y') # Let's say it should use MixinB
print(b2.name, b2.__class__.__base__)
print(b1.name, b1.__class__.__base__)
```

This will output:

```
A <class '__main__.MixinA'>
B <class '__main__.MixinB'>
B <class '__main__.MixinB'>
```

What can I do so that changing base class of `b2` will not effect `b1`. So the output should be:

```
A <class '__main__.MixinA'>
B <class '__main__.MixinB'>
A <class '__main__.MixinA'>
```

Or is there any other ways where I can access/execute all the properties/methods of the appropriate mixin applied dynamically to that object.

**Edit:** Updated description and code snippet for more clarity.

Comment: Root problem: `b1.__class__` and `b2.__class__` both refer to the same instance of `M`, so you can't simply modify its `__bases__` attribute. You need to replace `b1.__class__` and `b2.__class` with a new class altogether. But at that point, you may as well acknowledge that what you really want are subclasses of `B` defined on the fly with the appropriate mix-in, so that `b1` and `b2` never have the same type to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the inspiration from @chepner comments and the solution proposed, I have 2 solutions. The idea is same as creating a new dynamic class that compose of both the original class and the mixin class.

**Solution 1: Using Metaclass**

```
class M(type):
  def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    obj = type.__call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    if hasattr(obj, "mixin"):
        new_cls = type(cls.__name__ + obj.mixin.__name__, (cls, obj.mixin), {})
        new_obj = type.__call__(new_cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return new_obj
    return obj
```

**Solution 2: Using Factory**

```
def factory(cls, *args, **kwargs):
  obj = cls(*args, **kwargs)
  if hasattr(obj, "mixin"):
    new_cls = type(cls.__name__ + obj.mixin.__name__, (cls, obj.mixin), {})
    new_obj = new_cls(*args, **kwargs)
    return new_obj
  return obj
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the base class of an existing object, define an appropriate subclass before instantiating `B`. This doesn't require a metaclass at all, just a factory function. Something like

```
class A:
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

class MixinA:
    pass

class MixinB:
    pass

_cache  = {}
def compose_classes(base, *mixins):
    t = (base, ) + mixins
    if t not in _cache:
        name = f'{base.__name__}With{''.join(x.__name__ for x in mixins)}'
        _cache[t] = type(name, t, {})
    return _cache[t]

b1 = compose_classes(B, MixinA)()
b2 = compose_classes(B, MixinB)()
b3 = compose_classes(B, MixinA)()
```

`b1`, `b2`, and `b3` are all instances of `B`, and `b1` and `b3` are instances of the same subclass of `B`. (I.e, `type(..., (B, MixinA), {})` is only created once.)

Comment: The code snippet I provided is a simplified one. The problem for me is, I don't know which mixin should be used before instantiating an object. The mixin should be resolved from an attribute of that object.

Comment: How does the attribute get set in the first place? The metaclass feels like a bandage on a bigger problem.

Comment: Yes, it's part of a bigger problem but solving that is out of my scope. `__init__ `calls an external API and that returns name of the mixin.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can't modify `B`, and can only find out the mixin you want to use by creating an instance of `B` first? You should probably use composition instead: create the instance of `B`, extract the mix-in, *then* use `compose_classes` to create a class that *wraps* the existing instance of `B`.